# How to layout a VideoView next to TextView with scrolling list underneath

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm trying to have a VideoView fixed on the upper left with a TextView immediately to the right of it.  Below both of those I want a scrollable list of checkboxes, and below that two buttons "prev" and "next".  The VideoView and TextView should not scroll, just the checkboxes and buttons.  I can't seem to make this work with Linear layouts so i tried RelativeLayout but it seem kinda clunky because I'm hard coding all the relative stuff.  What's the best way of laying out this type of thing?

thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic layout that fits your description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_below="@id/chk1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If the `VideoView` is to big maybe you'll want to limit the space available to it by using the `0dp` value and `layout_weight` attribute on the enclosing `LinearLayout`.